# What does it mean when the publisher of an application is identified as Microsoft Corporation but then it is flagged as not verified?

Tags: signature

I am using this utility called SysInternals which is like the task manager on steroids for the Windows operating system. I noticed that the publisher of certain applications is labelled as Microsoft Corporation but then it also says that the application is not verified. I understand how code signing works. How is it possible that the publisher is verified correctly but the application is not verified?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about how Windows reports some security properties, now how cryptography is involved in these security properties. It would be on-topic on [su].

Comment: The signing certificate may be expired? SysInternals is actually a collection of many utilities like procexp and regmon, and some of them are fairly old, like pipelist.